# Mrs. Fakes curious puzzle

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

My favorite high school teacher, Mrs. Fake, is one of the most interesting people I can pretend to know.  She is a woman of a rather complex descent being related to both Caligula of Rome and King Ahab on both sides of her family tree.  She was my home room teacher in the 9th grade. Every morning around 8 o'clock she would post a problem on the board for the  in the class to lock horns with.  One day in the middle of March this is what she wrote.

4d 69 f3 d9 6e f3 d8 20 68 f3 d9 20 6d f3 dg 27 f4 9e 72 20 73 68 f3 d0
6h 67 73 68 f4 81 6h 6f 65 0d 6h f3 d1 20 79 f4 de 20 74 f7 92 6h 67 20
73 68 75 f7 90 0d 6d 69 f3 d9 6e f3 d8 20 64 f3 d0 6i 20 78 69 f3 d0 2f
20 64 f7 8h 70 f3 e2 6f 65 20 74 f4 81 20 64 65 20 67 75 f4 81 6h 6g 69
f7 8h 6h 2f 0d 6d f3 dg 27 f4 9e 72 20 6f f3 d1 69 6f 65

Please explain your method of solving this puzzle for extra credit.
As a reminder your book report on John W. Nystrom is due Friday.

Comment: Please explain your method of decryption. Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure this has something to do with the ascii characters. `20` appears quite often which is a Hex number for a space character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be a nursery rhyme.

> The ciphertext consists of the characters `0-9` and `d-i`. Clearly this is Caesar-shifted hexadecimal data. After reversing the Caesar shift and converting from hexadecimal beck into binary, I ended up with this:
>  
>  Ji\xc3\xa9k\xc3\xa8 h\xc3\xa9 j\xc3\xad'\xc4\x9br sh\xc3\xa0ngsh\xc4\x81nle\nn\xc3\xa1 y\xc4\xab t\xc7\x92ng shu\xc7\x90\nji\xc3\xa9k\xc3\xa8 d\xc3\xa0o xi\xc3\xa0, d\xc7\x8ep\xc3\xb2le t\xc4\x81 de gu\xc4\x81nmi\xc7\x8en,\nj\xc3\xad'\xc4\x9br l\xc3\xa1ile
>  
>  This didn't look very promising until I tried printing it as Unicode (UTF-8) text:
>  
>  Jiékè hé jí'ěr shàngshānle
>  ná yī tǒng shuǐ
>  jiékè dào xià, dǎpòle tā de guānmiǎn,
>  jí'ěr láile
>  
>  After a quick bit of googling around, I discovered that Jiékè (杰克) is Chinese for "Jack", and shàngshānle (上山了) means "up the hill". On a hunch, I tried [translating](https://translate.google.co.uk/) the well-known nursery rhyme:
>  
>  **Jiékè hé jí'ěr shàngshānle**
>  杰克  和 吉尔  上山了
>  Jack and Jill went up the hill
>  
>  **ná yī tǒng shuǐ**
>  拿 一 桶   水
>  to fetch a pail of water
>  
>  **jiékè dào xià, dǎpòle tā de guānmiǎn,**
>  杰克  到  下， 打破了 他 的 冠冕
>  Jack went down, and broke his crown
>  
>  **jí'ěr láile**
>  吉尔  来了
>  And Jill came (tumbling after)
>  
>  Note: The last line translates simply as "Jill came", but this is probably just an error on the part of Google Translate. I also had to change the 3rd line to "Jack *went* down" instead of "Jack *fell* down".

Comment: If anyone's interested, [here's a better translation](http://st.hujiang.com/topic/165554539148/).

Comment: Assuming you have the right plaintext, as far as I can tell the last line isn't an error on the part of Google.

Comment: @Sp3000 I mean the translation *into* Chinese appears to be wrong. I don't think the OP is an expert in the language, but then neither am I...